# Join top 3 interest fields along with each user row

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, group-concat

I'm trying to get the top 3 interests of each user, probably as a LEFT JOIN query.

The way the app is designed, each user has a set of interests which are no other than 'childs' (rows without `parent`) of the `categories` table.

Here are some simplified table schemas w/mock data (see **[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de815/1)**)

```
-- Users table

| ID |  NAME |
--------------
|  1 |  John |
|  2 |  Mary |
|  3 | Chris |


-- Categories table                           -- Interests table

| ID |                 NAME | PARENT |        | ID | USER_ID | CATEGORY_ID |
--------------------------------------        ------------------------------
|  1 |      Web Development | (null) |        |  1 |       1 |           1 |
|  2 |          Mobile Apps | (null) |        |  2 |       1 |           1 |
|  3 | Software Development | (null) |        |  3 |       1 |           1 |
|  4 |    Marketing & Sales | (null) |        |  4 |       2 |           1 |
|  5 |             Web Apps |      1 |        |  5 |       2 |           1 |
|  6 |                  CSS |      1 |        |  6 |       3 |           1 |
|  7 |                  iOS |      2 |        |  7 |       3 |           1 |
|  8 |      Streaming Media |      3 |        |  8 |       3 |           1 |
|  9 |                  SEO |      4 |        
| 10 |                  SEM |      4 |
```

To get the top 3 interests of a given user, I've usually performed this query:

```
SELECT `c`.`parent` as `category_id` 
FROM `interests` `i` LEFT JOIN `categories` `c` ON `c`.`id` = `i`.`category_id` 
WHERE `i`.`user_id` = '2' 
GROUP BY `c`.`parent` 
ORDER BY count(`c`.`parent`) DESC LIMIT 3
```

This query returns the top 3 `categories` (parents) of user with id = 2

I would like to find out how I can query the users table and get their top 3 categories either in 3 different fields (preferred) or as a `group_concat(..)` in one field

```
SELECT id, name, top_categories FROM users, (...) WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3');
```

Any ideas how I should go about doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: So, you want one row for each user (1,2,3)? And each row would have show their top 3 categories?

Comment: Exactly, like: `'1', 'John', 'cat_id1,cat_id2,cat_id3'` or `'1', 'John', 'cat_id1' , 'cat_id2' , 'cat_id3'`

Comment: if a user only has 2 interests is null what you want to see 3rd and if a user has 4 interests, what rules govern the 3 you want?to pick the  "top 3"?  Lastly your sample data above shows users 1,2, and 3 all having the same interest Web development in all cases.  would you want web development listed 3 times or do you want distinct interests?

Comment: @xQbert if a user has just 2 interests I don't mind whether it omits it or returns `NULL` on the 3rd one. The result has to be however the top 3 **category fields**. e.g. if a user has the most interests in "Marketing & Sales" then the first expected result for top_categories should be `4`, followed by any other "category parents" where they have the most interests

Answer (score 0):

First build a groped query that lists on distinct rows, the top three skills for each user. Then pivot that into to pull the three skills for eah user out to the right. You will need to use the Max(isnull(skill,'')) expression on the skills in each skill column.

Comment: Pieter, can you show how you'd do that with some code? Thanks!

Comment: I use  sql-server, not mySql, so my syntax knowledge for MySql is deficient; am also going offline in a minute. Try me tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It is very crude way of doing it in MYSQL to get top 3 records for each user

```
 SELECT u.id, c.name 
 FROM 
     users u, 
     categories c, 
     (SELECT i.id, 
         i.user_id, 
         i.category_id, 
         @running:=if(@previous=i.user_id,@running,0) + 1 as rId,
         @previous:=i.user_id
     FROM 
         (SELECT * FROM intersect ORDER BY user_id) i JOIN 
         (SELECT @running=0, @previous=0 ) r) i
 WHERE 
     u.id = i.USER_ID AND
     i.CATEGORY_ID = c.id AND 
     i.rId <= 3
 group by u.id, c.name ;
```

Hope it helps

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44ca6/8)